# This loop will only ever run once. Bad quoting or missing glob/expansion?

Tags: bash

Im working on a bash script that recive a list of processes and do a bunch of things with them, however when I want to analyze them with a loop this error happens.
Here is some code:

```
#! /bin/bash 

ls /proc | grep ^9 > processes.txt 

cat processes.txt 

for line in $processes.txt
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

PD: Im preatty new to bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` does parameter expansion; it does not expand a file name to the contents of the file.

Use a `while` read loop instead.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < processes.txt
```

Comment: That worked!!, Thanks for helping man